# Is a class wide integer that is only assigned at the start thread safe for reading its value?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

If I have a variable which is assigned to at the start of the program and then the program creates a few threads and then refers to it, is it thread safe?

```
private int myVal

private void StartOfApp()
{
  myVal = 99;
}

private void MethodCalledFromVariousThreads()
{
  int i = 100;
  if (i > myVal)  //Is reading this variable thread safe?
  {   
    //Do Stuff
  }
}
```

}

Comment: @AdamRalph: Not necessarily. Only make things that are constants that are *logically constant for all time*. For example "const int CurrentVersion = 2;" is bad; the current version will not be 2 in a couple of years, so that quantity was not *constant* even if it was only written once.

Comment: @Eric: I agree that with public constants this is a consideration, but with a private constant, it should be safe no?

Comment: @AdamRalph: Sure. Now, are you the kind of person whose attitude towards safety is "I'm going to do this dangerous radioactive thing, but it is actually 'safe' because I'm doing it inside a lead box", or are you the kind of person whose attitude is "I'm not going to do this dangerous radioactive thing even if it is contained in a lead box"?  I say *follow best practices always*, even when failing to do so hurts no one.

Comment: @Eric: having given this some thought, I think you are right. I guess the analog of opening 'the lead box' would be making the constant non-private at some point. (Personally I blame Resharper for always suggesting that I change my private and local single-assignment variables to constants ;-) - I've now changed that option!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is thread safe. Because you are never writing to the variable ( I assume ) it's data is, in essence, immutable. ( Ok, so it really is mutable because this is C#, but you get the idea ). Because of this, it will always return the same value and is thusly thread safe to read from.

If you never write to a variable, except when creating it, then it will always be thread safe to read from.

Comment: the variable is being written to by the line `myVal = 99;` The code as stated is not thread safe. You would have to ensure that the assignment is complete before the comparison.

Comment: This is true, my assumption is that myVal is being written to during the constructor of the object we are talking about.

Answer (score 2):

It's fine as long as you can guarantee that `StartOfApp` will complete the assignment before `MethodCalled`.

This would be better , imo:

```
private const int myVal = 99;

private void MethodCalledFromVariousThreads()
{
  int i = 100;
  if (i > myVal)  //Is reading this variable thread safe?
  {
    //Do Stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: I agree with your example but the 99 is a user defined value assigned at the start of the app so its not constant

Comment: Then passing it in the constructor is a good idea.  The constructor must finish before constructing thread can pass the instance to a new thread.

Comment: +1: given the initial Q, I would make this a constant. Given the additional requirement that this be a user defined value, I would also assign in a constructor to give thread safety.

Comment: Thanks @Adam Ralph - ah Validation. :)